# How to fix maven dependency it.sauronsoftware issue?

Tags: java, maven, dependencies, maven-2, maven-3

I'm trying to build an web aplication in my work and i just can't resolve this issue:

**Error**

[image]

I need this to work, but i don't know how to correct it, i really thank you if you can help me and if you don't thank you for read to this far.

Comment: What repository are you pointing to get that artifact? As fas I can see in https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/it.sauronsoftware there is no artifact named javae

Comment: The given dependency does not exist in Central...can you explain where it exists? Are inside corporate environment?

Comment: Hello, first of all, thanks for answer me, here is the only reference that i found to this dependency http://www.sauronsoftware.it/projects/jave/ i didn't find it in the maven repository either. Can i download it and add to my project manualy? I'm new on java web so apologize for any missinterpretation.

Answer (score 0):

if you have the jar in your local disk,but not registed in maven central,please install it into your local maven warehouse manually.
the command is similar below,please replase the artifactId,groupId and others to what your need.

> mvn install:install-file -Dfile=jboss-as-sprint-int-5.0.0.GA.jar
>   -DgroupId=jboss -DartifactId=jboss-as-sprint-int -Dversion=5.0.0 -Dpackaging=jar

then,open the terminal and execute the command.